# How do I get this heatmap on R to not normalise my data?

Tags: r, heatmap, normalization

I'm trying to display some data on heatmap in R comparing expression levels across cyclin types & body parts. If you look at the data below you can see that the expression of cyclin A1 in the brain is the same as cyclin A2 in the brain. [image]
However, when we look at the heatmap they are displayed as different colours. [image]I've tried normalising the data using the scale argument by column (default seems to be row) but that just results in any data without a difference in variance coming out as blank (e.g. brain cyclin A1 & A2 would be displayed as white despite their being expression).

I've attached my code below for a different organism (but the same code was used)- how is it best to fix this?

```
 #Anolis carelinensis Cyclin A
    #importing data- Anolis carelinensis
    AnolisA<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
    #all data in the matrix must be numerical 
    #therefore I need to remove the left column
    AnolisA2<-AnolisA[-grep('X', colnames(AnolisA))]
    #converting dataframe to a matrix
    AnolisA3<-as.matrix(AnolisA2)
    #builting the heatmap
    heatmap(AnolisA3)
    #remove dendogram and reordering of columns/rows
    #no scale argument applied because we are interested in the variation 
    #between both organs and cyclin types
    heatmap(AnolisA3, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA)
    #adding axis labels
    heatmap(AnolisA3, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, xlab="Organ", ylab="Cyclin")
    #creating a vector for column names
    rowname<-c("A1","A2")
    #altering labels
    #labRow- change row names
    rownames(AnolisA3)<-rowname
    #cexCol- alters column text size
    heatmap(AnolisA3, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, xlab="Organ", ylab="Cyclin",cexCol=1,cexRow=1.5,margins=c(11,4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with the `scale=` argument. I think this is what you're looking for with `scale="none"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~brain, ~heart, ~kidney, ~liver, ~skeletal,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1, 0, 0
)
mat <- as.matrix(df, nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
rownames(mat) <- c("A1", "A2")
heatmap(mat, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, xlab="Organ", ylab="Cyclin",
        scale = "none", cexCol=1,cexRow=1.5,margins=c(11,4))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>